# Multiple screens in one Tab Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am new to React Native and I am trying to create an app with a bottom tab navigator. However, in `HomeScreen.js`, which is the first tab navigator screen, I want the user to be able to navigate to antoher screen by pressing a button, while in the same Tab Navigator.

For example: In `HomeScreen.js`, when the user presses a button it navigates to `AnotherScreen.js` while staying in Tab Navigator which is, in this case, the Home one.

This is my `Apps.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import newPassScreen from './screens/newPassScreen';
import BaseScreen from './screens/BaseScreen';
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';

import DrawerNavigator from './screens/Drawer/DrawerNavigator';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import NotificationScreen from './screens/NotificationScreen';
import MessageScreen from './screens/MessageScreen';

import helder from './screens/companies/helder'

import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'
if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }

const AppContainer = createStackNavigator(
  {
default: createBottomTabNavigator (
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-home' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
    Message: {
      screen: MessageScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-chatboxes' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },      
    Notification: {
      screen: NotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-notifications' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: DrawerNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-person' size={24} color={tintColor}/>
      }
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
        if (navigation.state.key === 'Post'){
          navigation.navigate('postModal')
        } else {
          defaultHandler()
        }
      }
    },

    tabBarOptions:{
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      showLabel: false
    }
  }
),
postModal:{
  screen: HomeScreen
}
  },
   {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Base: BaseScreen,
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen,
  Password: newPassScreen
}, {
  initialRouteName:''
}
)

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
  Loading: LoadingScreen,
  App: AppContainer,
  Auth: AuthStack
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Loading'
}
  )
)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: So you need a StackNavigator maybe? Try to create a stacknavigator called homestack for example where you can have nested screens but the main one can be your home component. After that you  have to call the homestack as screen in your tab naviagtion

Comment: I already have a stack navigator. How do I nest it into the code?

Comment: If you have the stack Navigator set up and the first screen is for example your home component then just change the screen property to the stackNavigator inside the TabNavigator

Comment: That's where I am at, I have difficulties changing it properly and I need some help here

Comment: What version of react navigation are you using??  Also something is wrong in your code because i see you creating a stack navigator and inside that you create a tab navigator. your stacknavigator should be created outside and then you can take its name as a screen name inside the tab navigator - if there is more inside your navigator file update it and tell me your react navigation version pls

Comment: "react-navigation": "^4.3.7" - I will update with my whole App.js code

Comment: It's updated now

Comment: I will upload a navigation file i made for an app using react navigation 4.x - take a look at it maybe you can spot some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import SecureScreen from "../screens/SecureScreen";
import WetterScreen from "../screens/WetterScreen";
import SecureLogin from "../screens/SecureLogin";
import TermineScreen from "../screens/TermineScreen";
import SavedImages from "../screens/SavedImages";
import Expo from "expo";

import {init} from "./db";
import {initDB} from "./dbTodo";

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

init()
.then(() => {
  console.log("Database initialized! - Secure")
})
.catch(err=> console.log("DB ERROR: " + err))

initDB()
.then(() => {
  console.log("Database initialized! - ToDo")
})
.catch(err=> console.log("DB ERROR: " + err))

const SecureStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: SecureLogin,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Security Login"
    })
  },
  Secure: {
    screen: SecureScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Safe Folder"
    })
  },
  SavedImg : {
    screen: SavedImages,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Locked Images"
    })
  }
});

const tabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
  Wetter: {
    screen: WetterScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: () => {
        return <Ionicons name="md-cloudy-night" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
      },
      title: "Wetter"
    }
  },
  Termine: {
    screen: TermineScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: () => {
        return <Ionicons name="md-clipboard" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
      },
      title: "Termine"
    }
  },
  Secure: {
    screen: SecureStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        if (focused) {
          return <Ionicons name="md-unlock" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
        } else {
          return <Ionicons name="md-lock" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
        }
      },
      title: "Secure"
    }
  }
},
  {
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: "black"}
  }
);

const mainNavigator = createAppContainer(tabNavigator);

// export default Expo.registerRootComponent(mainNavigator);
export default mainNavigator;
```

As you can see I have a StackNavigator and inside my tabnavigator I call the stack as a screen! It is important that you also look up my last lines because in react navigation you need to createAppContainer on your tabnavigator (mainnavigator). Does this code help you undertand the structure? feel free to ask if something might be unclear and ignore the  init() functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my problem! How do I disable to title from the stack navigator?